# Python script: convert random date formats to fixed yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: python, date, converters

I'm quite new to python and don't know much about it but i need to make a small script that when someone inputs a date in any format , it would then converts it in to yyyy-mm-dd format. 
The script should be able to share elements of the entered date, and identify patterns.

It might be easy and obvious to some but making one by my self is over my head.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Many date formats are ambiguous. 9/11 means November 9th in large parts of the world.

Comment: Date parsing can not be done in an unambiguous way. So your question about "any format" can only be answered: not possible.

Comment: How are you going to read them? As a string? How is your program supposed to know which is the local way of interpreting dates order?

Comment: Use [`dateutil`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil); it already solved the arbitrary-input-parsing problem; it can be configured to interpret ambiguous dates one way or the other.

Comment: Have a look at [dateutils](http://labix.org/python-dateutil). There's a `dateutil.parser` that has several options. For the second part (converting to yyyy-mm-dd) `datetime` module has documentation on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this (not tested)

```
import locale
import datetime
...
parsedDate = datetime.strptime(your_string, locale.D_FMT)
print datetime.strftime(parsedDate, "%Y-%M-%d")
```

This assumes that the user will use its own local convention for dates.

Answer (score 2):

This is a difficult task to do yourself; you might want to take a look at [`dateutil`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) which has a rather robust [`parse()`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-c0e81a473b647dfa787dc11e8c69557ec2c3ecd2) method that you can use to try and parse arbitrarily formatted date strings.

Comment: Note that this would require installation of an extra python module, not necessarily an easy thing for a newbie.

Comment: @GreenMatt something that inevitably will have to be learnt though - and certainly less of a learning curve than re-inventing the wheel...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strftime` for output (your format is `"%Y-%M-%d"`).

For parsing input there's a corresponding function - `strptime`. But you won't be able to handle "any format". You have to know what you're getting in the first place. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to tell a difference between (for example) American and other dates. What does 01.02.03 mean for example? This could be:

- yy.mm.dd
- dd.mm.yy
- mm.dd.yy